# SQL statement to show difference between every user choice and one user choice

Tags: php, sql

Basically I need to create output TOP table where users are arranged by comparing their points with admin's points.
For example:

```
User3 | 0 //Everything was as admin had.
User5 | 3 //One song had 2 points different from admin and one was off by one
ect.
```

In my database I have three tables:

```
Table: rating

+------------+---------+----------+---------+ 
| rating_id  | user_id | song_id  | points  | 
+------------+---------+----------+---------+ 
| 1          | 1       | 4        | 0       | 
| 2          | 1       | 3        | 1       | 
| 3          | 3       | 2        | 3       | 
| 4          | 4       | 2        | 2       | 
| 5          | 2       | 1        | 4       |


Table: songs

+---------------+------------+ 
| song_name_id  | song_name  | 
+---------------+------------+ 
| 1             | Song1      | 
| 2             | Song2      | 
| 3             | Song3      | 
| 4             | Song4      | 
| 5             | Song5      | 

Table: users

+----------+----------+----------+
| id       | username | password |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | User1    | passw    |
| 2        | User2    | wordp    |
| 3        | User3    | somet    |
| 4        | User4    | hings    |
```

It should be something like this (not in any programming language):

```
Compare user_id > 1 with user_id=1 //Let's say that the comparable admin is user_id=1
$result= ABS(user.points-admin.points)++;
```

And put this to array as:

```
username => result
```

Then when I sort this array by result, I can print it as top table - who got the closest result to admin!

I tryed several different solutions but never got the right result.

Can anybody help me?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks!

With JOIN the result is:

```
+------------+---------+----------+---------+-----------+
| song_id    |song_name| user_id  |username |rating_diff|
+------------+---------+----------+---------+-----------+ 
| 1          | Song1   | 1        | admin   | 0         | 
| 2          | Song2   | 1        | admin   | 0         |
...etc...
```

With LEFT JOIN the result is:

```
+------------+---------+----------+---------+-----------+
| song_id    |song_name| user_id  |username |rating_diff|
+------------+---------+----------+---------+-----------+ 
| 1          | Song1   | 11       | user2   | NULL      | 
| 1          | Song1   | 10       | user1   | NULL      |
| 1          | Song1   | 12       | user3   | NULL      |
| 1          | Song1   | 1        | admin   | 0         |
| 2          | Song2   | 11       | user2   | NULL      | 
| 2          | Song2   | 10       | user1   | NULL      |
| 2          | Song2   | 12       | user3   | NULL      |
| 2          | Song2   | 1        | admin   | 0         |

..etc..
```

So.. Something is wrong, the rating_diff does not work.

Comment: Which SQL (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want this comparison on a song-by-song basis (instead of a total or average across all songs), try:

```
select r.song_id,
       s.song_name,
       r.user_id,
       u.username,
       abs(r.points - r1.points) rating_diff
from rating r
join songs s on r.song_id = s.song_name_id
join users u on r.user_id = u.id
join rating r1 on r.song_id = r1.song_id and r1.user_id = 1
order by s.song_name, abs(r.points - r1.points)
```

This should sort the output by the song name, and then by the difference between the admin's points and the users' points. (Change the join on `rating r1` to be a left join if you can't guarantee an admin rating for every song.)

Comment: Thanks! i use mySql and this query almost works, but something is still wrong.. could you please check out my question, I updated it. :)

Comment: But Admin and the default user have the same songs just they use different order.
And the comparison should be song-by-song, but the result is SUM'ed up like:
user1 20p missed
user2 15p missed
user3 0p - exactly the same order as admin

Thanks ;)

Comment: @Algeron: Oops, my mistake! I should have joined the ratings on song_id, not rating_id. I have now amended my query - can you give it a try?